# Namespace issue on Blazor WASM Page

Tags: c#, blazor, webassembly, .net-5

I am currently having an issue with my Blazor pages.

After working on a project and closing Visual Studio 2019 Community, I get a namespace error on my pages.

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0234  The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'MyProject.Pages.System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

This is on a .razor component, but it does this on all the components in my project and only seems to happen when I close VS and open in again later.

My folder structure has subfolders in the pages folder:
e.g.
Pages
-AccessMan
-Users
-UsersList.razor

I have tried:

1. Close VS and reopen
2. Clean, Build
3. Clean, Rebuild
4. Delete obj and bin folders and Clean, Build

I have all my namespaces in my _Imports.razor as nothing changed and it worked before I closed VS for the day.

Missing reference include

1. Linq
2. Collections
3. Threading
4. HttpClient
5. Task
6. DateTime

I have tried to add the required namespaces to imports. still not workiing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `System` as a namespace in your project, so it's conflicting with the Microsoft `System` namespace.

Simplest fix is use a different name, e.g. `MyProjects.Pages.MySystem` or something similar.

Comment: So simple thanks, but why would it conflict when the namespace "path" differs?

Answer (score 4):

I had same issue. Actual answer is below.

```
@using global::your.conflicted.namespace
```